# How to detect that video was opened in player with .NET C/C++/C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, video

Imagine that we have Windows OS and some video player (f.e. VLC media player or GOM Player). Is there any way to catch played videos (for example: file name or path of opened movie) in .NET, besides using players APIs (most of them don't have any public API).

Thanks for advices.

Comment: No reliable way to do it in such general definition.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, most of these programs won't go through some standard Windows library to display the videos - maybe DirectShow or Media Foundation, but you won't get 100% coverage that way.

If you **just** want the file name or path, you could [monitor files with HookAPI.dll](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30537/Windows-File-Monitoring-System-Using-Windows-API-H) and check the file extension for the common video formats (avi, mp4, mov, flv, etc.)

Comment: In .NET you would just create P/Invoke bindings for HookAPI or use existing bindings like [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/). This **might** get mixed up with search indexing, but you can probably find a way to differentiate user-opened files from search indexing/background processes.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I think closer you can go,is, monitoring the [`video file formats`](http://www.fileinfo.com/filetypes/video) in [`MainWindowTitle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle.aspx) of [`processess that's running`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx) and/or look if movies players is running.

```
var videoFileFormats = new List<string>
{
  {".3gp"},
   {".mp4"} //etc.. 
};

var players = new List<string>
{
     {"wmplayer"} //etc..
};

 var processes = Process.GetProcesses();

 foreach (var proc in processes) {
       try {

         string appName = proc.ProcessName;
         string appFileName = proc.MainModule.FileName;
         string appExt = Path.GetExtension(appFileName);

         if (videoFileFormats.Contains(appExt) || players.Contains(appName)) {
               //do something..
               //found..
         }

        } catch (Exception E) {
              //it's because you can't get some process of system.
         }

   }
```